# Fluent Nhibernate composed entity, specify foreign key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Fluent Nhibernate map like :

```
 public class UserMap : ClassMap<PortalUser>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        WithTable("aspnet_Users");
        Id(x => x.Id, "UserId")
            .GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Name, "UserName");
        Map(x => x.Login, "LoweredUserName");
        WithTable("LdapUsers", m => m.Map(x => x.FullName, "FullName"));

    }
}
```

My foreign key column in table "LdapUser" is UserId but the select that gets generated is going to look for a "PortalUserId".
Is there a way to specify the relation key direcly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
WithTable("LdapUsers", m => {
    m.Map(x => x.FullName, "FullName");
    m.WithKeyColumn("UserId");
});
```

Comment: I think you mean m.WithKeyColumn("UserId");

Comment: WithTable is creating a <join> element and, if I understand correctly, <key> is supposed to refer the the key column on the joined table.  Ronnie said his foreign key is "LdapUser" so the query should look something like ... FROM aspnet_Users a INNER JOIN LdapUsers b ON a.UserId = b.LdapUser.

My reference: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/04/24/Multi-Table-Entities-in-NHibernate.aspx

But you could be right, Jamie; I honestly have no idea... I've never had to use this construct. :)

Comment: Actually my foreign column was "UserId" in table "LdapUser" and putting it instead of "LdapUser" worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked... and sorry Jamie, you were dead on but I wasn't paying enough attention apparently. I updated my post in case someone stumbles upon this later.

Comment: Hey Stuart this is ok for setting the key of the linked table but it automatically joins with the primary key of the base table. How to setup a join with a different column that is not the pk?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible to be honest. You might want to create a new question for that and link back to this one for full context. You're likely to get more exposure for your new question that way... maybe someone else knows a way to do it.